# How to sort a html table with a checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, sorting

how can i connect my check box with a table . let's say my table has 2 rows the first is Male the second is Female my checkboxes are male and the next one is a female. so the thing i want is when i check my Female checkbox the female row will move to the first row in the table and the male will move to the second row in the table . I am doing it in notepad++ with html

Answer (score 0):

Try using **[Knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/index.html)**

I've used knockout:

- [Checked Binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/checked-binding.html)
- [Foreach Binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html)
- [Text Binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/text-binding.html)
- [Observabe Array](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html)
- [Subscribe](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html)

### Html

```
<div> 
    <input type="checkbox" name="name" value="Male" data-bind="checked: maleChecked" />Male
    <input type="checkbox" name="name" value="Female" data-bind="checked: femaleChecked" />Female
</div>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Gender</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: users">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: age"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: gender"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

### JavaScript

```
var users = [
        { "name": "AAA", "age": 22, "gender": "Male" },
        { "name": "BBB", "age": 21, "gender": "Female" },
        { "name": "CCC", "age": 26, "gender": "Female" },
        { "name": "DDD", "age": 24, "gender": "Male" }];

var vm = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.users = ko.observableArray(users);
    self.maleChecked = ko.observable(false);
    self.femaleChecked = ko.observable(false);

    self.maleChecked.subscribe(function (value) {
        if (value) {
            self.femaleChecked(false);
            self.users.sort(sortByMale);
        }
    });

    self.femaleChecked.subscribe(function (value) {
        if (value) {
            self.maleChecked(false);
            self.users.sort(sortByFemale);
        }
    });   
}

var sortByMale = function (a, b) {
    return a.gender > b.gender ? -1 : 1;
};

var sortByFemale = function (a, b) {
    return a.gender < b.gender ? -1 : 1;
};

ko.applyBindings(new vm());
```

Here is the **<kbd>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/p5NKQ/2/)</kbd>**